# Ronin M, S or Zhiyun Crane 2 for BMPCC4k

Tags: stabilisation

I am currently figguring out which gimbal I should use for my BMPCC4k with SIGMA 18-35 in a TILTA cage and SSD recording.

I sorted it down to Ronin M, S or Zhiyun Crane 2 but am stuck here.

The things I figured out/think about them:

> Ronin M:
>   +Most ways to hold it, most max weight.
>   -Not so much space to balance and handle cables
>
> Ronin S:
>   +Reputable brand
>   +Better interface
>   +Barrel roll
>   +Slightly more payload
>
> Zhiyun Crane 2:
>   +Cheaper
>   +Follow Focus (Which I don't need)
>   +Slightly more pitch (I don't think thats needed)
>   - Slower turning
>   +Longer battery
>   -Seen some jittering in Potato Jets Videos

It looks like the Ronin S is the best match for BMPCC4k, but is it worth the 120$ more? (For me it is 699$ vs 579$)

Thanks.